# Consuming streaming data using Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to consume some streaming data from a [Twitter endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/filtered-stream/overview). Can I do this with Spring Integration with the [Stream Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/stream.html#stream)?

If this is possible, any examples of how to do this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"Stream Support" is for reading from stdin and writing to stdout, stderr.

There is an [extension project for twitter support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/spring-integration-social-twitter).

You should also look at the [Spring Cloud Stream samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/tree/master/applications/sink).

Comment: You should also look at the [Spring Cloud Stream samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/tree/master/applications/sink).

Comment: OK thanks Gary, I'll take a look. I don't think the extension project handles a streaming endpoint  but I'll look at the Cloud Stream in more depth. I potentially could use the [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#streaming) API as well.